# No photo when sharing an url pointing to wix

Tags: facebook, url, dns, sharing

I have a domain registered www.elliniki-paradosi.gr.  My colleague has made a free wix site http://andprokopis.wix.com/elliniki-paradosi.

I have made DNS forwarding (masking) the domain www.elliniki-paradosi.gr to the wix page http://andprokopis.wix.com/elliniki-paradosi.  The DNS forwarding works fine

We tried to publish the link www.elliniki-paradosi.gr in our facebook accounts but the link to be shared shows only the title and the description of the page, not a preview of the site or the uploaded image for social media.

How can this be fixed ?

My domain company (papaki.gr) prompted me to you as the holder of the site.

I have tried the facebook debugger with no luck.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? It seems to be working for me now.

Comment: it is still an issue !!!